# Loading an ArrayList into a JCombobox using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, arraylist, jcombobox

Currently have an ArrayList called *SundayList* which is loaded as soon as the frame *AddStudent* is loaded (bit of GUI)

The code automatically generated by Netbeans is:

```
comboboxSunday = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

comboboxSunday.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item1", "Item2" }));
```

How do I load the combobox items with  my own array?
The array includes items such as:

```
Activity1
Activity2
Activity3
Activity4
```

From my previous search, people mentioned about using a `toString()` and `toArray()`, and I'm not familiar with either methods, and how they help in loading the list into the combobox as I'm quite new to java..

Comment: check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15332328/2024761). It'll show you how to add Custom objects to ComboBox. Instead of creating objects 1 by 1 there, you can traverse through your `ArrayList` and add all the objects to it.

Comment: It does seem like the answer to this, but for me, I'm not familiar with mySQL, and I'm trying to avoid foreign things for me

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own `ComboBoxModel` that takes a `List` as the main parameter, but that's a little more involved

```
comboboxSunday.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
for (Object item : listOfItems) {
    comboboxSunday.addItem(item);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this method, but when I call my arraylist "SundayList", I get the cannot find symbol error, unable to call the list to this method. what should I do?

Comment: Post so e additional code.are you using a String array or an ArrayList?

Comment: Using ArrayList: initialized as such: List<String> sundayList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: And you replaced listOfItems with sundayList in the for-loop?

Comment: Yup, I went into customize code in Netbeans, and added the for loop right below the code as shown above, except that it's "javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel()", cause Netbeans need it that way

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array looks something like this:

```
String[] SundayList = { "Activity1", "Activity2", "Activity3", "Activity4" };
```

You can do this:

```
javax.swing.JComboBox sundayCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox(SundayList);
```

If your array isn't a string array. try:

```
javax.swing.JComboBox sundayCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox(SundayList.toString());
```

Hope this helps!